# Cant push data to reatime database firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

im making a page that to push a number to realtime database firebase, but when i click on the button to push number nothing happen. this is my code

```
<form>
    <input type="text" id="id"><br>
    <button id= "addbtn">make_nfc</button>
</form>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/10.6.0/firebase-app.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/10.6.0/firebase-database.js"></script>
<script>
    const firebaseConfig = {
        apiKey: "AIzaSyD4QdzB3fd2FTw2bZlEiR5_HW9x1O_9mH8",
        authDomain: "pet-care-20a90.firebaseapp.com",
        databaseURL: "https://pet-care-20a90-default-rtdb.firebaseio.com",
        projectId: "pet-care-20a90",
        storageBucket: "pet-care-20a90.appspot.com",
        messagingSenderId: "752435918706",
        appId: "1:752435918706:web:c87a176a2f47d757c4cfeb"
};
    firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
    const database = firebase.database();
    const f_id = document.getElementById("id").value;
    const addbtn = document.getElementById("addbtn");
    addbtn.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
         e.preventDefault();
        database.ref('id').set(f_id.value);
});
</script>
```

hope u guy can help me fix this

Comment: You've defined `const f_id = document.getElementById("id").value` and then used `f_id.value` which means that you're using the `value` property of a `string` which is `undefined`.

Comment: thanks but it still not work . i just add console.log("hello") in add event listener and realize that notthing happen when i click on the button. i think the button is not work

Comment: You should be checking your console for errors. In your case, several module related errors and _"firebase is not defined"_

Answer (score 1):

See [Alternative ways to add Firebase to your JavaScript project](https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/alt-setup).

Firebase v9+ uses a modular system so top-level objects like `firebase` no longer exist.

Your code should look more like this where specific service functions are imported from the relevant modules.

```html
<form>
  <input type="text" id="id"><br>
  <button type="button" id="addbtn">make_nfc</button>
</form>

<!--    Note the `type="module"` -->
<script type="module">
// import app functions
import { initializeApp } from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/10.6.0/firebase-app.js";

// import RTDB functions
import {
  getDatabase,
  ref,
  set,
} from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/10.6.0/firebase-database.js";

const firebaseConfig = {
  /* ... */
};
const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
const database = getDatabase(app);

const f_id = document.getElementById("id"); //  note there is no `.value` here
const addbtn = document.getElementById("addbtn");

addbtn.addEventListener("click", async (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  await set(ref(database, "id"), f_id.value);
});
</script>
```

---

Alternately, you can keep your original code by using the [*namespaced* (*compat*) libraries](https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/modular-upgrade#about_the_namespaced_compat_libraries).

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/10.6.0/firebase-app-compat.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/10.6.0/firebase-database-compat.js"></script>
```

Accessing these from the CDN is undocumented so I would not recommend it. Also...

> ❗️ Keep in mind: the compat libraries are a temporary solution that will be removed completely in a future major SDK version (such as version 10 or version 11). Your ultimate goal is to remove compat code and keep only the modular-style code in your app.